# Передача значения переменной в другую страницу

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Как по MVVM передать значения переменной string из Page1 в Page2?

Comment: Положите её в общую VM. </thread>

Comment: Мне нужно в Page1 придать значение переменной, и это значение передать в Page2. Допустим у меня в общей VM - `string Pas`. Что я делаю в Page1VM, и что в Page2VM? Я вот в конструкторе Page1VM сделал так: `Page1VM text = new Page1Vm();` `text.Pas = this.Pass`...если я правильно понял, конечно...а что в Page2VM делать?

Comment: Если надо на постоянной основе общую - то должен быть общий класс. Если передавать в какие то моменты - события могут подойти.

Comment: То есть вы имеете ввиду, что в отдельном классе будет `public string Pas { get; set; } и все? Я с MVVM только знакомлюсь, и все эти Binding, ViewModel общаюсь недавно, поэтому я прошу примера конкретного, чтобы я его разбирал

Comment: Зависит от того, как по логике связаны две страницы. Обычно создаются ВМ согласно каким то аналогиям в обычном мире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эх. Ну ладно, давайте разжуём.

1. Заводим общую часть данных в виде отдельной VM:

   ```
   public class CommonVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       string pas;
       public string Pas
       {
           get { return pas; }
           set { if (pas != value) { pas = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
       }

       void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
       {
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        
   }
   ```
2. Заводим по VM для каждой страницы:

   ```
   class P1VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public P1VM(CommonVM commonVM)
       {
           CommonVM = commonVM;
       }

       public CommonVM CommonVM { get; private set; }

       // и не забудьте реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged
   }
   ```

   и такой же `Page2VM`.
3. В VM-части вы должны создать `MainVM` и в нём внутренние VM:

   ```
   public class MainVM
   {
       public MainVM()
       {
           var commonVM = new CommonVM();
           P1VM = new P1VM(commonVM);
           P2VM = new P2VM(commonVM);
       }

       public P1VM P1VM { get; private set; }
       public P2VM P2VM { get; private set; }
   }
   ```
4. Теперь View. Вы не должны в MVVM пытаться из View устанавливать `DataContext`, это не в компетенции View. Когда будете создавать View, сразу навешивайте нужный `DataContext`:

   ```
   var p1 = new Page1() { DataContext = mainVM.P1VM };
   var p2 = new Page2() { DataContext = mainVM.P2VM };
   ```
5. Внутри `Page1` делайте `Binding` на нужное свойство:

   ```
   <TextBox Text="{Binding CommonVM.Pas}"/>
   ```

Вроде всё.

Comment: Если именно заявленный в шапке page1 -> page2, то можно было обойтсь p1vm -> p2vm, с однонаправленной зависимостью. Но в целом - да, выглядит логично и удобно. Если бы автор описал сущности, было бы проще понять,что ему надо.

Comment: @Monk: Я из соображений «на вырост», да.